Django: How to undo ModuleNotFoundErrors due to multiple site-packages locations
When I run my Django project, why does it check for site packages in a folder other than where my project is located? The correct location where the project and package files are located is:
C:\Users\mattk\Box\WeConsent

But in the error thread below, it seems to be searching in two separate locations for my library files:
C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\Scripts\python.exe  # my packages are not located here
C:\Users\mattk\Box\WeConsent\manage.py runserver localhost:8000  # my packages are located here.

Where in PyCharm can I specify to ignore this location: C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\Scripts\python.exe when loading my packages?
from traceback in Terminal:
C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:\Users\mattk\Box\WeConsent\manage.py runserver localhost:8000 
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"C:\Users\mattk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mattk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\PythonProjects\VoterSay7\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\mattk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2_provider'


You have to run pip install django-oauth2-provider or pip3 install django-oauth2-provider (depending on your Python or Python3 interpreter) to make sure the dependency is there, also verify your Python interpreted in PyCharm is same as the one used with pip or pip3.

You are running the python.exe from a different venv (VoterSay7) to launch your development server, that's why it uses that venv's site-packages directory. When creating the project in PyCharm you must have chosen the wrong interpreter.

Strange, because the Python Interpreter is:  Python 3.9(Weconsent) C:\Users\mattk\Box\WeConsent\venv\Scripts\python.exe......Do I need to create a new virtual environment in order to fix this?
